# How to assign weekdays to buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text field, 7 buttons in viewcontroller

```
@IBOutlet weak var courseDesc: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var sundayButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mondayButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tuesdayButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var wednedayButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thursdayButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fridayButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saturdayButton: UIButton!
```

How to assign these 7 week days below to 7 buttons above, for example, if user clicks `sundayButton`, it should be assigned as `Sunday` when user saves it.

```
func getWeekDay() -> [String] {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
    calendar.locale = NSLocale.current as Locale
    return calendar.weekdaySymbols
}

var assignDay =  getWeekDay()

let sunday = assignDay[0]
let monday = assignDay[1]
let tuesday = assignDay[2]
let wednesday = assignDay[3]
let thursday = assignDay[4]
let friday = assignDay[5]
let saturday = assignDay[6]
```

Comment: You might need to break this into smaller parts.  I don't understand what you're trying to do.  We'll be more likely able to help you solve small individual coding tasks, not one large conceptual one.

Comment: @Frankie, please see edited question

Comment: What does this have to do with Core Data?

Comment: @matt, I edited question, which was big, I just shortened it. So I am removing the tag

Comment: Still unclear what you want to do. What does "assign a weekday" even mean? Did you want the weekday names to be the _titles_ of the buttons?

Comment: I want the button to function as weekday, instead of date picker, I want to use buttons.

Comment: @Coder221Yes start with the 'assigning' because you're already missing concepts.  You don't want to assign a weekday to a 'button'.  My guess is you want to assign a certain date to a data object when a certain button is pressed which can then later get saved.  So what's your data object here?  If you're not ready for Core Data then practice by creating a class or struct to hold your assigned data, then print it out to see if you've done it correctly.  Then study up on core data so you can persist that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this question from you a few times, and you're still not wording it very well. But let's see if I can help.

You're trying to store a string in each button, so that you can grab that string from the barbuttonitem.

You could do it a few ways.

One: You could extend UIBarButtonItem, give it a property like

```
var day: String?
```

then set that property for each button and grab the value in your save function (while accounting for it being optional). Probably don't want to do that, because you extend all barbutton items and maybe you don't want that.

Two: You could make a little dictionary:

```
  let buttonDays: [UIBarButtonItem: String] = [SundayButton: "Sun",...]
```

and then in save you can just grab the day by accessing this dictionary like so. (it's an optional so if let unwrap it)

```
 if let day = buttonDays[sender] {...}
```

Three: You could assign each button a tag, and use that tag in a dictionary as above.

```
sundayButton.tag = 0
mondayButton.tag = 1
....
let dayForTag : [Int: String] = [0: "Sun",...]
//then in save function
let day = dayForTag[sender.tag]
```

You dont need to use a dictionary above, just an array, since it is zero indexed.

But finally, you need to ask yourself. ***Why are you bothering to store these strings in your data model anyway?*** You model doesn't give a damn what the name of the day is. Only a human knows that. And you are already going to store the value of the weekday. That value can be directly turned into a day of the week when you come back to the controller layer of your app. Strings are much bigger than a 16 byte int, and you're creating redundancy in your model by storing both.

edit: turned application layer into controller. OSI model on my mind. Oops.

In that case, all you need to do is assign a tag for each button, 0 for sunday, 1 for monday etc etc. And then store that tag in your database. When you need to access Tasks for a specific day, search with the integer representation of that day, and not the string.

edit: I just remembered that I think Sunday is actually weekDay one in Date() objects, so you would have to account for that. I think. Been a while since I used it.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Appreciate your understanding of my problem. Now I completely get it :)